# mgt component refuses to render when providing a SimpleProvider

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

Building an angular app. Right now, I'm only trying to get the mgt-person element to render, but it refuses.

First, I installed with `npm i @microsoft/mgt`. That causes a runtime error because I have strict type checking on. I uninstalled it and went with what I needed. Installed the mg-components and mgt-element libraries.

Here's my AppComponent code.

```
ngOnInit() {
    Providers.globalProvider = new SimpleProvider(this.getAccessToken, this.login, this.logout);
    // getUserComputed makes sure the user is loaded in my service and ready to use
    this.oidc.getUserComputed().subscribe(() => Providers.globalProvider.setState(ProviderState.SignedIn));
}

signOut() {
    this.auth.signOutRedirect();
}

getAccessToken(options): Promise<string> {
    const obs = this.oidc.getUserComputed().pipe(map(x => x.access_token));
    return firstValueFrom(obs);
}

login(): Promise<void> {
    const obs = this.oidc.signIn();
    return firstValueFrom(obs);
}

logout(): Promise<void> {
    const obs = this.oidc.signOut();
    return firstValueFrom(obs);
}
```

`<mgt-person person-query="me" view="twoLines"></mgt-person>`

What am I missing? The getAccessToken method is never invoked.

Comment: For some reason, it started erroring again like I first mentioned. Turned one "skipLibCheck" and it's workin now

Comment: Hi @Luminous, Is the above issue has been resolved?